QGIS - Geometries constantly in error
I m doing a lot of polygon editing in QGIS for a mapping project (matching polygons up to aerial photo patterns) - mostly by manually moving nodes, using the Merge Selected Features and the Split Features tool.  But I m finding that after only a few edits, the polygons are corrupted eg split into two parts that I didn't intentionally create, 'ghost' nodes that can't be selected, duplicate polygons over the top of the one I just edited (that I didn't knowingly create) etc.  I can fix it by running 'Fix Geometries', but its happening so often (about every 4-5 edits), it slows me down.  I must be doing something wrong but I don't know what.  When I start a fresh project, it doesn't happen, but as I make more and more edits, I have to use the Fix Geometries tool more frequently.
Is there a 'correct' way to edit polygons (split them into 2 or more, merge polygons, moving nodes etc)?
I have ensured all layers are in the same projection (GDA2020 MGA zone 55 (EPSG7855)) - but does the ellipsoid setting have anything to do with it (it was set at GRS 1980 (EPSG7019), I assume automatically by the program)?
